# Scalar metric distances in uneven tensor space?

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a space T composed of 3 independent vector directions s, p, f of dimensions 3, 3, 6; each with values in [0,1]. I would like to compute scalar metric distances between points t1 and t2 in T.

One approach I've considered is the spectral radius of the Kronecker product of t1 - t2. This is the modulus of the square root of the largest magnitude eigenvalue of the K-product. What others are worth examining?